# Search minimum absolute value difference in java

Tags: java, search

How can I optimize my algorithm to find the minimum absolute value difference in a given array. Here is my approach which checks each and every element and returning the value.

```
static int minAbsVal(int[] myArray){

    ArrayList<Integer> diffs= new ArrayList(); // all absolute value differences

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.length; j++) {
            if (myArray[j]!=myArray[i]){
                int absVal =Math.abs( myArray[i]- myArray[j]);
                diffs.add(absVal);
            }

        }
    }


    int min = diffs.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < diffs.size(); i++) {
        if (min>diffs.get(i)){
            min = diffs.get(i);
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this solution. If array contains duplicates than it returns 0 if you wanna avoid than you can add conditions also.

```
static int minAbsVal(int[] myArray){

            Arrays.sort(myArray);
            ArrayList<Integer> diffs= new ArrayList<Integer>(); // all absolute value differences

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++) {
                diffs.add(Math.abs( myArray[i+1] - myArray[i]));
            }

            Collections.sort(diffs);
            return diffs.get(0);
        }
```

Or you can also use :-

```
static int minAbsVal(int[] myArray){

        Arrays.sort(myArray);
        int minimum=Math.abs( myArray[1] - myArray[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < myArray.length-1; i++) {
            int diff = Math.abs( myArray[i+1] - myArray[i]);
            if (diff == 0)
                return 0;
            else if (minimum > diff)
                minimum = diff;
        }
        return minimum;
    }
```

Comment: This does not do the same thing OP's code does. It only checks successive elements and as you pointed out, doesn't filter zeros.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thats why I have written if you wanna avoid 0 than simply add conditions

Comment: Sorry. Totally missed the sort operation. This is indeed the right answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check the following solution,

```
static int minimumAbsoluteDifference(int n, int[] arr) {
    int a = Math.abs(arr[1]-arr[0]);
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for(int x=0;x<n-1;x++){
        if(Math.abs(arr[x]-arr[x+1])<a){
            a = Math.abs(arr[x]-arr[x+1]);
            if(a==0){
               return a;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependson the size of your array a good approach would be to divide it in different smaller arrays and look for the minimum of each in pararell and then compare those results .

Anyways you dont need so many iterations, you can just set the baseValue to the first element of the array and when iterating the array compare the baseValue vs the current, if the current is smaller then asign baseValue to current (I would rename baseValue to minValue in that case)

Comment: The way OP has it, you need to check all elements against each other.

Comment: You have to pre-sort the array to do it in chunks